# Docker save read arguments from stdin

Tags: docker, sed, zsh

In lieu of a `docker-compose save` command I've resorted to using sed to read the YAML file and piping this into `docker save`.

I'm seeing some strange behavior with docker reading from stdin. For example, I have a command that can find all the images in a docker-compose YAML file and output it to stdout

`sed -nr 's/image: "(.*)"/\1/p' docker-compose.yml | uniq | xargs -d '\n' | cat`

Will output:

`mysql    redis    python`

However if I try to pipe this into `docker save` I get the following error

```
sed -nr 's/image: "(.*)"/\1/p' docker-compose.yml | uniq | xargs -d '\n' | 
docker save  | gzip -c > images.tar.gz

"docker save" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker save --help'.

Usage:  docker save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)
```

How do I get docker to read from stdin for its arguments?

Comment: The same way you get any command to take arguments from stdin: `sed ...  | xargs docker save`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Forgot the appropriate use of xargs.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this with a proper answer, from William Pursell in the comments:

*The same way you get any command to take arguments from stdin: `sed ... | xargs docker save`*